# Extract the Element Value from the latest Node with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML code from which I need to extract the ID of the latest element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <JsonData>
        <Dokument_ID>26a914b5</Dokument_ID>
        <Dokument_Art>DIV</Dokument_Art>
        <Document_creation_date>02.12.2021 08:51</Document_creation_date>
        <Document_filesize>4234</Document_filesize>
    </JsonData>
    <JsonData>
        <Dokument_ID>cc88ae09</Dokument_ID>
        <Dokument_Art>DIV</Dokument_Art>
        <Document_creation_date>02.12.2021 08:54</Document_creation_date>
        <Document_filesize>184706</Document_filesize>
    </JsonData>
    <JsonData>
        <Dokument_ID>22f14c7b</Dokument_ID>
        <Dokument_Art>DIV</Dokument_Art>
        <Document_creation_date>02.12.2021 15:09</Document_creation_date>
        <Document_filesize>4234</Document_filesize>
    </JsonData>
</root>
```

With the following xpath I manage to get the ID number of the element with the largest Filesize

```
/root/JsonData[not(../JsonData/Document_filesize > Document_filesize)]/Dokument_ID
```

Unfortunately, this does not work the same way for the creation date.
My guess is that this is due to the fact that the content of Docment_creation_data is a date with special string characters.

What are the options for running the desired xpath?

Answer (score 2):

> *With the following xpath I manage to get the ID number of the element with the largest Filesize*
>
> ```
> /root/JsonData[not(../JsonData/Document_filesize > Document_filesize)]/Dokument_ID
> ```

I don't know which piece of software (with XPath support) you're using, but this would probably work too:

```
root/JsonData[Document_filesize=max(../JsonData/Document_filesize)]/Dokument_ID
```

> *Unfortunately, this does not work the same way for the creation date. My guess is that this is due to the fact that the content of `Document_creation_data` is a date with special string characters.*

Because of the custom format it's not an official dateTime. You'd have to convert it to one to do any comparisons.

The following intermediate steps are done with the command-line tool [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) I always use for XPath/XQuery:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e 'root/JsonData/Document_creation_date'
02.12.2021 08:51
02.12.2021 08:54
02.12.2021 15:09

$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  root/JsonData/replace(
    Document_creation_date,
    "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (.+)",
    "$3-$2-$1T$4:00"
  )
'
2021-12-02T08:51:00
2021-12-02T08:54:00
2021-12-02T15:09:00

$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  root/max(
    JsonData/dateTime(
      replace(
        Document_creation_date,
        "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (.+)",
        "$3-$2-$1T$4:00"
      )
    )
  )
'
2021-12-02T15:09:00

$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  root/format-dateTime(
    max(
      JsonData/dateTime(
        replace(
          Document_creation_date,
          "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (.+)",
          "$3-$2-$1T$4:00"
        )
      )
    ),
    "[D01].[M01].[Y] [H01]:[m01]"
  )
'
02.12.2021 15:09

$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  root/JsonData[
    Document_creation_date = format-dateTime(
      max(
        ../JsonData/dateTime(
          replace(
            Document_creation_date,
            "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (.+)",
            "$3-$2-$1T$4:00"
          )
        )
      ),
      "[D01].[M01].[Y] [H01]:[m01]"
    )
  ]/Dokument_ID
'
22f14c7b
```

Better yet, use XQuery:

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e '
  (
    for $x in //JsonData
    order by dateTime(
      replace(
        $x/Document_creation_date,
        "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (.+)",
        "$3-$2-$1T$4:00"
      )
    )
    return
    $x/Dokument_ID
  )[last()]
'
22f14c7b
```